# Transferring data from postgres to rabbitmq

Tags: postgresql, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I am quiet new to rabbitmq and currently trying to install Postgres listen exchange plugin at:
https://github.com/aweber/pgsql-listen-exchange

I tried following the instructions listed there but i am getting following errors:

/bin/sh: escript: command not found

make[1]: *** [deps.mk] Error 127

make: *** [../rabbitmq-server/dist/.done.0.0.0] Error 2

I am currently working on Mac, not sure if it is because of i missing some essential libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just install the plugin you have to:

1. Download the package here https://github.com/aweber/pgsql-listen-exchange/releases and exactly this https://github.com/aweber/pgsql-listen-exchange/releases/download/0.3.0-v3.5.x/pgsql-listen-exchange-0.3.0-v3.5.x.zip
2. Extract the zip and copy the files into the rabbitmq plug-in directory, usually this : `rabbitmq_server-3.5.4/plugins`
3. After that execute `sudo ./rabbitmq-plugins enable pgsql_listen_exchange`, and as result you should have:

> ```
> The following plugins have been enabled:   
> epgsql   
> pgsql_listen_exchange
> ```

you are trying to rebuild the package, but if you want just use it, you don't need to rebuild it.

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks !! I recieved following message The following plugins have been enabled:
  epgsql
  amqp_client
  pgsql_listen_exchange

Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@adityas-MacBook-Pro... failed.
 * Could not contact node rabbit@adityas-MacBook-Pro.
   Changes will take effect at broker restart.
 * Options: --online  - fail if broker cannot be contacted.
            --offline - do not try to contact broker.

Comment: Does it mean it will enable the next time i run rabbitmq ?

Comment: Thanks, i checked the list it says it's explicitly working and running on rabbit@adityas-MacBook-Pro.

Comment: Hi Gas, When i ran the plugin what is the queue name which i should receive on in python script. I tried queue name :"test" in python and also ran the command in postgres: (postgres=# NOTIFY test, 'This is a test';). But didnt get any data in my receive script in python

Comment: Hi @AdityaPatel ! I'm sorry but I don't know how this plug-in works. I just know how rabbitmq works with the plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

Here is new version of previously mentioned plugin - https://github.com/anshmain/listen-pg-exchange

Now works with rabbitmq:3.12

Installation guide inside, it's pretty the same

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.